# Random oversampling versus classes weighting for class-imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

I want to train a multi-class classification deep learning model. But my dataset is class-imbalanced. So considering 2 solutions, random oversampling and classes weighting, I have some questions:

1. Do random oversampling and classes weighting have the same effect
   on the model training? If they don't, what are the differences?
2. Which method is better? Why?

Comment: Better for what? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I edited the question.